# Sum of differences of circular permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ are arranged into a circle. What is the maximum sum of the differences $|x_1-x_2|+|x_2-x_3|+\ldots+|x_{n-1}-x_n|+|x_n-x_1|$?

I think the maximum should occur when the numbers are arranged $n,1,n-1,2,n-2,3,\ldots$, but how to prove it formally?

The sum for this arrangement is $(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+1+\lfloor n/2\rfloor = \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}+\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have any ideas? What sum do you get for your conjectured maximal arrangement?

Comment: So you get a mean difference of $(n-1)/2+\lfloor n/2 \rfloor/n$, I think too that this is the maximum, and I think we might perhaps be able to prove this by finding a contradiction if we assume that the mean difference is greater. (Separating the cases where n is even or odd.) But it really is a nice problem.

Comment: Intuitively, your first equation is never greater than the sum of $x_1+x_2+...+x_n$. Your second equation is almost equivalent to $\frac{n^2}{2}$, and the sum of the first $n$ integers is $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$. If the conjecture is true and you can show a minimal "loss" of approximately $\frac{n}{2}$ (perhaps from $x_n-x_1$) you have found the maximum.

Comment: This problem is often discussed in terms of arranging numbers on a dartboard (to maximise the penalty for poor aim) so searching for "optimal dartboard" or similar may help. I think, though I may be misremembering, that all arrangements that alternate between numbers from the top half of the range and numbers from the bottom half (as yours does) are equally good and as good as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is that $|x - y|$ is basically either $x - y$ or $y - x$. Either way, one term (either $x$ or $y$) inside the absolute will be positive, and the other term will be negative.

This means, if you have $n$ absolutes, you will have $n$ positive terms and $n$ negative terms. Now, each $x_i$ appears twice in all of these absolutes, so in total we have $2n$ terms. So, since we must have $n$ positive terms and $n$ negative terms, in order to maximize the sum, we want to make the larger $x_i$s positive and the smaller $x_i$s negative.

I will demonstrate the case where $n$ is even (odd is similar, but need some little more work). By the argument in the previous paragraph, the sum cannot exceed:

$$2( (n/2+1) + (n/2+2) + \cdots + n) - 2 (1 + 2 + \cdots + n/2) = 2 \frac{n}{4} (\frac{n}{2} + 1 + n) - 2 \frac{n}{4} (1 + \frac{n}{2}) = n^2 / 2$$

Which matches your bound.